# Custom font in angular 10 project is loaded in network, styles are applied but is not rendered on text

Tags: html, css, angular, custom-font

I have installed the custom font roboto in a new Angular project.

1. In the network tab the status is 200 for the roboto variants used in styles (regular and bold)
2. In the component I have a custom class with font-family: Roboto that is correctly applied to the p element.
3. I have added the roboto-fontface.css from the npm package to angular.json's styles array and is accessible from the dev tools sources tabs. I have defined in roboto-fontface.css a custom class that is applied to an element, so it load properly.

However, the roboto font is not applied to the p element.

[image: Styles are applied correctly]

[image: Font is loaded in network tab]

Answer (score -1):

Put your font files in /assets/fonts/
And then in scss define @font-face and use acordingly.

For example:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Source Serif Pro";
  src: url("^assets/fonts/source-serif-pro/SourceSerifPro-Regular.ttf") format("ttf");
  font-weight: 400;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Source Serif Pro', sans-serif;
}
```

Not need to install or put in angular.json

Comment: It might not be your need but it is my need. Thank you for the response though, if you have suggestions how to fix a font installed trough a npm package I'm happy to hear them!